# Sending zip file containing plain txt file via email

Tags: email, zip

How to send a plain txt file in a zip file via email in unix? The contents in the txt file should be word wrap.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: These are multiple questions: 1) how to word wrap a text file; 2) how to zip a plain txt file; 3) how to email a zip file as an attachment. What exactly  have you tried for each and what is not working?

Comment: @Matteo If you hover above the down vote arrow it says "This question does not show any research effort", I think that is applicable on each of the 3 questions asked.

Answer (score 2):

To wrap the text file you can use `fold` (see [fold man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fold))

For example

```
fold -w 78 -s input.txt > wrapped.txt
```

will wrap your text to a maximum width of 78 characters. You can then use `zip` to compress it

```
zip wrapped.zip wrapped.txt
```

and then send it per email with `mail`

```
mail -a wrapped.zip -s "Subject of the mail" recipient@example.com
```

(not all versions of mail support the `-a` option)

Answer (score 0):

If your mail don't support -a option, do it with uuencode:

> uuencode original_filename attachment_filename | mail -s "subject" recipient@xyz.com

for example (it's working in front of my eyes):

> uuenconde ~/.netrc mynetrc.txt | mail -s "test" xyz@xyz.com

and I see the attachment as mynetrc.txt in the mail.